# Iterative Mean, Covariance Algorithm Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, algorithms, statistical-inference, matrix-equations, parameter-estimation

The problem is to show that the following iterations converge to the vector $\mu$ and the matrix $\Sigma$.

We have data in the form of nx1 vectors $\mathbf{Q}_k$, $1 \leq k \leq N$ where
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{Q}_k\\ 
\mathbf{R}_k
\end{bmatrix}=U_k \mathbf{X}_k
$$
where $U_k$ are known unitary 2nx2n matrices of the form
$$
U_k=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta_{1k}) & \sin(\theta_{1k}) & 0 & 0 & 0&\cdots \\ 
0 & 0 & \cos(\theta_{2k}) & \sin(\theta_{2k})  & 0&\cdots\\ 
\vdots  &  & \vdots  &   & \vdots\\ 
-\sin(\theta_{1k}) & \cos(\theta_{1k}) & 0 & 0 &\cdots \\ 
0 & 0 & -\sin(\theta_{2k}) & \cos(\theta_{2k})  & 0&\cdots\\
\vdots  &  & \vdots  &   & \vdots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(permuted rotation matrices). Note that the angles are taken to be independent random values distributed uniformly on $[ 0, 2\pi]$.

$\mathbf{R}_k$ are unknown, and $\mathbf{X}_k \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are unknown.

To estimate $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, we iterate as follows:

Let our current estimate for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ be $m$ and $S$, respectively.
Let
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{Q_k}\\ 
m_{R_k}
\end{bmatrix}=U_km
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
S_{Q_k Q_k} & S_{Q_k R_k}\\ 
S_{R_k Q_k} & S_{R_k R_k}
\end{bmatrix}=U_kSU_k^T
$$
Where the components are equally-sized block-matrices.
We then form 
$$
m_{R_k|Q_k}=m_{R_k}+S_{R_k Q_k}S_{Q_k Q_k}^{-1}\left (Q_k-m_{Q_k}  \right )
\\
S_{R_k|Q_k}=S_{R_k R_k}-S_{R_k Q_k}S_{Q_k Q_k}^{-1}S_{Q_k R_k}
$$
Then, our updated estimates for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are
$$
\\
m'=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}U_k^T\begin{bmatrix}
Q_k\\ 
m_{R_k|Q_k}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
S'=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}U_k^T\begin{bmatrix}
Q_kQ_k^T & Q_km_{R_k|Q_k}^T\\ 
m_{R_k|Q_k}Q_k^T & S_{R_k|Q_k}+m_{R_k|Q_k}m_{R_k|Q_k}^T
\end{bmatrix}U_k
-m'm'^T
\\
$$
We then iterate.

My goal is to prove that this iteration converges for arbitrary starting vector $m$ and arbitrary positive-definite starting matrix $S$, and, in the limit as $N \rightarrow \infty$, that this converges to $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

Right now, I'm still having trouble with the n=1 case

Does anyone know of a method to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. A bound on some sort of distance measure in terms of starting point and number of iterations would also be great.